# I'm trying to print out something like "This is the prices with taxes" + the random number and the tax

Tags: php

I'm trying to print out something like "This is the prices with taxes" + the random number and the tax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$tax=0.06;

function random(){
    echo rand(1,100);
}

$prices = array();
$taxPrices = array();

for ($i =0; $i< 5; $i++) {
    $prices[$i]= random();
}

echo "The prices with the taxes";

for ($i=0; $i<count($prices); $i++) {

    $taxPrices[$i]=$prices[$i] * $tax;
    echo "<br>$prices[$i] = ".$taxPrices[$i];

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain what problem you're having with this? You've said what you want to do, and shown some code; now can you explain what's happening and how it isn't what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is echoing a value instead of returning it.

```
function random(){
    echo rand(1,100);
}
```

So...

```
$prices[$i]= random();
```

this won't work.

Do this to your function and you should get something going.

```
function random(){
    return rand(1,100);
}
```

Also, your echo is missing brackets. Use this:

```
echo "<br>{$prices[$i]} = ".$taxPrices[$i];
```

Take a look: http://ideone.com/nmbcqG

Comment: Thank you, it worked right away

Comment: Don't forget to pick an accepted answer then ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more OO approach. For this example, we have a constant declaring the tax amount and a constant declaring the currency prefix. There is two methods: each time we run the `createPrice()` method, it will generate a random price; each time we run the `getPrices()` method, it will output all prices **with** tax added.

Let's take a look at our class (or see a full working version at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NEmmd))

```
class Prices {
    CONST TAX = 0.6;
    CONST PREFIX = '£';

    private $TaxPrices = [];

    public function createPrice() {
        $this->TaxPrices[] = rand(1,100);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrices() {
        foreach($this->TaxPrices as $_price) {
            echo self::PREFIX . $_price * self::TAX . '.00';
        }
    }
}
```

We can now instance this class and use the object like so:

```
$p = new Prices();
for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $p->createPrice();
}
echo 'This is the prices with tax:';
$p->getPrices();
```

Comment: I think that's too advanced for him. He is probably a beginner and might get confused. But your approach is very nice!

Comment: Ah true, let it be a learning curve then. Thank-you for the feedback however @PhiterFernandes

Comment: Your code isn't very good in terms on solid oop design. It seems like Factory pattern but it is not. Class variables should not be named with capital letter at first and I don't know why you need fluent interface on createPrice method? Same applies for naming variables with `_` it's pratice from languages like c++ where private variables were named that way. Also with OOP you can easily implement iterator interface or use use generators(yield).

Comment: Its a skeleton, I am not going to code all of it for OP.  Also, the interface is only in there to show the output (normal use-case wouldn't have it inside the method). This isn't a review section, it solves OP's problem. If you disagree, create a new answer @Robert

Comment: I think it's too early for OP to go into solid OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the error that Phiter mentioned there are more things that could be done better.

1. It's really not needed to create the function only for rand(0,100)
2. You should not put count() or any other function inside the second argument of for loop unless its value changes. The count value won't change in your case so it can be declared outside as a variable for inside in first argument. See example.
3. Price with tax is rather 1 + $tax => 1.06 which is 106%. So example when you have number 100 then the price + tax 6% would be 106 so 100 * (1 + 0.06) is proper equatation.
4. If you format your code according to PSR rules is more readable.

**See the code below:**

```
<?php

$tax = 0.06;
$prices = [];
$taxPrices = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    $prices[$i] = rand(1, 100);
}

echo "The prices with the taxes: <br>";

for ($i = 0, $count = count($prices); $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $taxPrices[$i] = $prices[$i] * (1 + $tax);
    echo "$prices[$i] = $taxPrices[$i] <br>";
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
The prices with the taxes: 
54 = 57.24 
60 = 63.6 
81 = 85.86 
23 = 24.38 
68 = 72.08
```